# pyinstaller onefile not including data files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have an application I would like to package into a single file, but am running into issues with the `--onefile` option including html, js, and css files. The process works fine when running `--onedir` (of course after adding the path and desired path of the respective data files to the `data` in `analysis` of the .spec file.

I have tried the solution proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile), but after packaging I get an error `app name returned -1`. Furthermore, packaging to one file works fine when not including the code proposed by this answer, again missing the html, js, and css I need.

Has anyone run into this issue with pyinstaller 3.1.1 that has a fix?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up solving this one for myself. After reading through the docs again I noticed that here is a small blurb that says in one file mode the exe will create a temp folder named `MEIPASS` this is the folder referenced in the answer I linked. However, in my case as I have multiple data files that are swapped out in my app I had to change all of the references to those files to call `sys._MEIPASS+ '/' + file` instead of the `QDir.currentPath() + '/' + file` I had been using (This app was built using PyQt4).

Furthermore, for the CSS and js files associated with my html I had to make sure that the href calls where in the same folder.