# How to integrate .jpg image into python executable with PyInstaller

Tags: python, image, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable

I'm trying to create an executable from my python GUI script that displays a single image using tkinter.

My objective is to get the image and executable to be one file with the `--onefile` option in `pyinstaller`.

Unfortunately this isn't working and I need by image file to be in the same folder as the final executable for it to work. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller brings this functionality and it is [well-documented](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle) for the folder approach. For example

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'src/image.jpg:.' myscript.py
```

will copy the existing file src/image.jpg to the top level of the bundled app (specified as '.').

However how would you do it with a single file (`--onefile`)? Your script will find the file in a temporary directory: [Adding a data file in Pyinstaller using the onefile option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060894/adding-a-data-file-in-pyinstaller-using-the-onefile-option)

Comment: Does this mean, the person does not have to copy the image file? Just send the exe alone? Or does it not work with `-F`?

Comment: You need to access the bundled file like in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060894/adding-a-data-file-in-pyinstaller-using-the-onefile-option).

Comment: @acw1668 Providing the real answer in a comment ;)