# Why doesn't my pyinstaller extract any exe files

Tags: python

I created a project for my friend and I would like to ask how can I solve my problem with PyInstaller?

My problem is that when I type

> pyinstaller myprogram.py

It does create folders, but I can't find the `.exe` anywhere in them. It should be in dist, but it isn't.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple .py file with just a `print('Hello')`? If that works then the problem may be with one or more imports in your myprogram.py

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

The problem is that `pyinstaller` automatically bundles everything into your `myprogram` folder under `dist`. In that folder, you will find a `myprogram.exe` file that you can run. However, this isn't that convenient.

## Solution

Adding the option, `--onefile`, such that `pyinstaller --onefile myprogram.py` should bundle all files into one `exe` under the `dist` folder.

`-F` will also work; however, it's less readable if you're going to come back to it later.

## Footnotes

This will create a console when you run the `.exe` file - if you have a GUI in your script (like Tkinter or PyQt), use `--windowed`.

Alternatively, you could do `--onedir` and send your friend an entire folder - may be a little easier.

Adding the `--add-data {filename}:DATA` will bundle files with your exe - use `sys._MEIPASS` (see [this great StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061279/15350738)).

And finally, if you're just printing stuff, the console window will close as soon as everything's done.

See [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) for other options commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

> **Solutions**

This may seem obvious but- delete the files created by pyinstaller and run pyinstaller again.

If that doesn't work try and reinstall pyinstaller.

In worse case scenario, Use another software to make .exe files from .py files.